# Cross reference Facts and Dimensions in Data warehouse

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am trying to design a data warehouse for a licensing vendor, who sells licenses on ecommerce and various other venues. The things they want to track are sales, product lifecycle and activity. What this means is that there are different sale types (such as new purchase, promotional purchase, renewal) and different events/states of a license, such as - a license can get installed, renewed, activated, registered. A license can get renewed many times (on different dates).

So I was thinking my dimensions would be very simple - date, product, source, saletype and event/state. I would have two fact tables; one would be for sales, and another would be for the events, both of them having foreign keys to the dimension tables. My fact tables would be an accumulating fact table, where every event would add a new row - hence, the licenses can be repeated. However, the requirements states that they be able to cross reference these two facts and the saletype and event dimensions. For example, If someone sees that product 'A' has 100 sales in the US ecommerce store of type 'new purchase', then they want to see how many of 'those' 100 licenses also got activated... and then maybe they would want to see, out of the people that activated, how many have registered... and then (back to saletype) of how many of those that registered, how many of them 'renewed'. And I cannot really define a heirarchy, because you could have a whole lot of combinations of these....

How can I do this? As I'm reading, I find there seems to be no way to relate the two facts based on the license itself (which is what I need to do).

Also, I was also thinking that maybe I can have 1 fact table, and I can 'technically' combine the saletype and the eventtype into a big eventtype dimension. So, then in the fact table would be a big transaction fact table, which will have an eventid foreign key to the events dimension. But still, so now I have a fact table, with a row for every event that happens to a license. The license is repeated, and one event can appear for an event more than once (on different dates). So, if I choose to see the totals for an event, how can I see how many of those licenses also exist for a different event?

I need to provide all these numbers as measures, so that a business user can see them on the fly (using whatever OLAP browser they want to use)

note: I am using SQL server analysis services and SQL server 2008 r2

Just as a reference, this is what I have now:

1. DimProducts (PK: ProductID, and other attributes)
2. DimDate (PK: DateKey, and other attributes)
3. DimEvent (PK: EventID, and oither attributes)
4. FactLicenses(FK: ProductID; FK: DateKey; FK: EventID, and License Field(varchar))

So I have a license repeated, with an event for every time something happens to the license (installed, activated, renewed, cancelled, renewed (again). It is possible there is one license with the same eventID, but never on the same DateKey. The primary key of the table is DateKey + EventID + License

EDIT:

So, I've read in many places that the fact table in a situation like this should be an accumulating fact table, which has multiple columns pointing to the same (type) of dimension - (i.e. date) and that I should create role playing dimension for each one of those. But How do you account for the fact that a license can get renewed multiple times, and can get installed multiple times, etc...?

Comment: it's too complicated at least for me. can you make it shorter and simpler... for instance include your table structures you created so far as an example to understand you better and then ask your question giving some examples. because I am currently working on BI as well.

Comment: making it shorter would defeat the purpose - I think I've presented the business scenario that I need to model in detail (and I've stated the table structure I have, too).

Comment: @MR: no, i meant not your scenerio, your explaination :)

Comment: hmm - which part is confusing? which part should I explain more clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since gone back to Ralph Kimball's book, and found a case study that can solve this issue for me. I've also merged the sale type and event types into one major group. So given that, there are still two groups of things - things that can happen to a license once, vs things that can happen to a license multiple times. Everything that can happen to a license once is now stored in an accumulating fact table. Everything that can happen to a licene multiple times is then stored in a different table (a different table for each entity or 'type' of event that can happen).

This effectively solved the problem for me, because in analysis services, I am now able to make something called 'referenced' relationship, where the relationship is the 'license'. So any of my dimensions that are related to the different table can be linked via the original accumulating fact table (that has the license column).

Thanks for your input, whoever has tried to answer.

Comment: Can you tell us which case study you found in Kimball's book? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design already accommodates this type of analysis, though really your situation is comprised of two queries.

The first would be if you wanted to find out the number and value of sales by summing values in the SALES fact table for product 'A' and source 'USA'. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) TOTAL_UNIT_SALES, SUM(FCT_SALES.VALUE) TOTAL_VALUE
FROM   FCT_SALES, DIM_PRODUCTS, DIM_SOURCES
WHERE  FCT_SALES.PRODUCT_FK = DIM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_SK
AND    DIM_PRODUCTS.NAME = 'A'
AND    FCT_SALES.SOURCE_FK = DIM_SOURCES.SOURCE_SK
AND    DIM_SOURCES.NAME = 'USA';
```

The second would pivot or sum records in the EVENTS fact table for the same set of dimensional foreign keys, to find how how many events occurred of each type. For example:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DIM_SALE_TYPES.NAME = 'NEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_NEW_SALES
,      SUM(CASE WHEN DIM_SALE_TYPES.NAME = 'ACTIVATION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_ACTIVATIONS
,      SUM(CASE WHEN DIM_SALE_TYPES.NAME = 'REGISTRATION' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_REGISTRATIONS
FROM   FCT_EVENTS, DIM_PRODUCTS, DIM_SOURCES, DIM_SALE_TYPES
WHERE  FCT_EVENTS.PRODUCT_FK = DIM_PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_SK
AND    DIM_PRODUCTS.NAME = 'A'
AND    FCT_EVENTS.SOURCE_FK = DIM_SOURCES.SOURCE_SK
AND    DIM_SOURCES.NAME = 'USA'
AND    FCT_EVENTS.SALE_TYPE_FK = DIM_SALE_TYPES.SALE_TYPE_SK;
```

Comment: But how do I do this from SSAS pont of view? I don't know beforehand that they would ask for a combination like that, so I need to have the measures on hand, so that when users are browsing the cube (via excel or something else) these numbers are available. I'm not sure I can expect them to write queries. On the other hand, I'm not sure I can make calculated measures of ALL the possible combinations...

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSAS, but any BI tool with support for OLAP can generate these types of queries from a dimensional model. The point I'm making is that an analytical query is usually on a single fact table, so there should be no need to cross-reference them - and even in cases where they are based on multiple fact tables, the tool should be able to do this based on the constraints.

Comment: Its not going to work entirely. Because the date keys can be different. For example - a license thats gets bought in april can be installed in may. So the fact sale date is april, and the event sale date is may. So if I join on all the original dimensions (from the first query), it is still missing the license. It is possible that there were other installs in may, which are unrelated to licenses that were purchased in april. I can't really use the license as a join (in a SSAS query) because its not a dimension.

Comment: You still seem to be thinking in terms of joining the fact tables together - in reality this won't happen. The only shared dimensions between the two fact table queries, as I see it, are the Product and Source dimensions. The rest of the dimensional keys, including the date ones, relate to either query's specific purpose, i.e. total sale dollars in April for USA, or total license activations in May for USA. 

If I wanted to "drill down" on a particular sale to see its events (activations, registrations etc), I would just use the shared dimensional keys to query the other fact table.

Comment: That doesn't work. Just the dimensions in itself is not enough, because the same dimensions may have less licenses (its a subset). I could make the license itself a degenerate dimension, but I'm still unclear as to how I would make it work....

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest adding license as a separate dimension. Can it be associated with some unique identifier, say, license number or activation key?

Comment: Yes it can - I've since done that, but I'm still struggling to make the connection between one fact table and another, specifically in sql server analysis services..